# How to Send Attachment Data w/ Ionic Cordova EmailComposer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to send an email with an attachment in my Ionic app, using the [Phonegap plugin found here](https://github.com/jcjee/email-composer). One of the features of this plugin is to attach a file or file as Base64.

The email is sending fine, but it never attaches a file so it makes me think im doing something wrong forming my string. Specifically, I'm attempting to create a CSV, and attach it as a string.

Here's what my call looks like:

```
if(window.plugins && window.plugins.emailComposer) {
        window.plugins.emailComposer.showEmailComposerWithCallback(function(result) {
            //success callback
        },
        "Feedback for your App", // Subject
        "",                      // Body
        ["whatever@whatever.com"],    // To
        null,                    // CC
        null,                    // BCC
        false,                   // isHTML
        null,                    // Attachments
        [["filename1","data:text/csv;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADwAAAA8CAYAAAA6/..."]] // Attachment Data
      );
    }

  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with a similar issue.

Looking in the [EmailComposer source](https://github.com/jcjee/email-composer/blob/master/src/android/EmailComposer.java) for Android the attachmentsData array is treated as follows:

```
JSONArray fileInformation = attachmentsData.getJSONArray(i);
String filename = fileInformation.getString(0);
String filedata = fileInformation.getString(1);
byte[] fileBytes = Base64.decode(filedata, 0);
```

So the data part should be pure base64 data.  If you change your line:

```
[["filename1","data:text/csv;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADwAAAA8CA...
```

to

```
[["filename1","iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADwAAAA8CAYAAAA6/..."]]
```

you might find it works.